# How do we figure out which replicationcontroller is actually managing the pods in case of deploymentconfig, openshift cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-enterprise, minishift

So, lets say I have a `DeploymentConfig` running and because of that a `ReplicationController` which is eventually running a pod. If I updated the `DeploymentConfig`, more than once (let's assume), more `ReplicationControllers` would be created, and pods would be run by the one of the `ReplicationController`.

Now if I have `Deploymentconfig` details how do I figure out which `ReplicationController` is actually managing the pods? One way I know is getting the `deploymentconfig.status.latestVersion` and match that with the value of the annotation `openshift.io/deployment-config.latest-version` of `ReplicationController`. But is this the way people do it?

Answer (score 0):

Query the replication controller object using label. Deployment, rc and pods contain matching label

If you update the deployment then a new replication controller get created and rolling update is triggered. post that old rc object get deleted.

Comment: Yeah, but if there are more than one replication controller all of them are going to have same label.

Comment: And by the way thwre is difference between deployment and deploymentconfig, it seems you used them interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

To continue from P Ekambaram's answer.

As long as You are not using another application to maintain pod customization like mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/#writing-programs-for-replication). There is a chance that all of the replication controllers actually maintained a deployment.

According to kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/#using-replicationcontrollers-with-services):

> #### Using ReplicationControllers with Services
>
> Multiple ReplicationControllers can sit behind a single service, so that, for example, some traffic goes to the old version, and some goes to the new version.
>
> A ReplicationController will never terminate on its own, but it isn't expected to be as long-lived as services. **Services may be composed of pods controlled by multiple ReplicationControllers, and it is expected that many ReplicationControllers may be created and destroyed over the lifetime of a service (for instance, to perform an update of pods that run the service).** **Both services themselves and their clients should remain oblivious to the ReplicationControllers that maintain the pods of the services.**

Hope it helps.